# Getting the user's domain name for a print job from the Print Spooler API

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, print-spooler-api

How can I get the domain name of the user making a print given the Job ID of the print?

I can get the user's name from, e.g., the JOB_INFO_2 retrieved via GetJob, but none of the JOB_INFO_# structures contain the user's domain name.

I can get the print server's domain using `IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName`, but that may not be the same as the user's domain, so it's not a reliable solution.

Comment: Is it true that the user can print to a printer on another domain *without* providing a valid logon for that domain? I don't know myself but I'm wondering if maybe the print server's domain is good enough.

Comment: This was originally logged as a [bug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/156473) in NT 4.0 >pUserName member of JOB_INFO_2 structure does not include domain information.

Comment: @randcd - the link doesn't go to the right place.

Comment: @CareyGregory it works ok for me.  What's wrong with the page?  The issue reported is one of a number listed in the same article, though at the time this was a GDI structure or was lumped in with them for the sake of the bug.  Perhaps it was never addressed since the use case would be rather fringe.

Comment: @randcd - Sorry, I was looking for a more detailed report on the bug, but now I see what you're referring to.  I guess this tells us how soon Microsoft will be fixing it.  NT4 is, what, 13 years obsolete?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure, but it occurs to me that maybe the user name will include the user's domain (somelike name@domain), and maybe that only happens if the user is printing to a printer in another domain. It might be worth writing some code and checking this out.

Comment: I know it does not include the domain for a user on the same domain, but it does seem like it's worth checking to confirm that the behavior is the same for a user from a different domain.

Comment: I don't have access to an environment where I can check this myself, so if you do check this out then please share the results.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(PrincipalContext, IdentityType, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344891.aspx) to find the user by username. Once the user is found, get the domain with that UserPrincipal's Context property.

You'll need to add a refernce to System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.

Comment: Post working code that demonstrates your idea and it's worth 50 points to you.  There is a 24-hour grace period on the bounty.